# could not initialize BCCSP Factories: Could not find default `PKCS11` BCCSP

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, pkcs#11, hyperledger-fabric-peer

I am running Hyperledger Fabric v2.2.3 from github release, in Oracle Linux 8.4
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.3.3/hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-2.3.3.tar.gz

I am running the orderer and peer without dockers.
and I am running PKCS11 using SoftHSM 2.5.0 without FabricCA.
I have also followed the guide at official document to setup the PKCS11.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/hsm.html
I have also read this stackoverflow post stating that need to remove the `SW` section.
[peer node start throwing Could not find default pkcs11 BCCSP error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956298/peer-node-start-throwing-could-not-find-default-pkcs11-bccsp-error)

I successfully generated the token, the certs for both Orderer and Peer.
My Orderer started everythings successfully, but not my Peer.

Question: is the pre-built peer binary in github release for v2.2.3 is not built with PKCS11 enabled ?
Am I need to build the peer myself to enable the PKCS11 support ?

```
2021-09-15 10:05:50.583 +08 [bccsp] GetDefault -> DEBU 001 Before using BCCSP, please call InitFactories(). Falling back to bootBCCSP.
2021-09-15 10:05:50.585 +08 [bccsp] GetDefault -> DEBU 002 Before using BCCSP, please call InitFactories(). Falling back to bootBCCSP.
2021-09-15 10:05:50.594 +08 [bccsp] GetDefault -> DEBU 003 Before using BCCSP, please call InitFactories(). Falling back to bootBCCSP.
2021-09-15 10:05:50.595 +08 [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 004 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /appl/blockchain/peerOrganizations/org1/users/Admin@org1/msp: could not initialize BCCSP Factories: Could not find default `PKCS11` BCCSP
```

My Peer core.yaml

```
    BCCSP:
        Default: PKCS11

        PKCS11:
            Library: /appl/softhsm/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so
            Label: fabric
            Pin: 123456
            Hash: SHA2
            Security: 256
            Immutable: false
```

My directory structures and files at the peer.
You may ignore the tls, as I am not using any tls at this moment.

```
[user@hyperledgerfabric org1]# tree users
users
└── Admin@org1
    ├── msp
    │   ├── admincerts
    │   ├── cacerts
    │   │   └── ca.org1-cert.pem -> ../../../../ca/ca.org1-cert.pem
    │   ├── config.yaml
    │   ├── keystore
    │   ├── signcerts
    │   │   └── Admin@org1-cert.pem
    │   └── tlscacerts
    │       └── tlsca.org1-cert.pem -> ../../../../tlsca/tlsca.org1-cert.pem
    └── tls
        ├── ca.crt -> ../../../tlsca/tlsca.org1-cert.pem
        ├── client.crt
        └── client.csr
```

## Update after compiled peer with PKCS11 enabled:

Now it gives the error not able to find KeyMaterial:

```
2021-09-17 10:50:44.513 +08 [bccsp_p11] getECKey -> DEBU 019 Private key not found [Key not found [00000000  9e c0 9a a7 5c df 5b 13  25 61 15 a4 d2 8c f3 ba  |....\.[.%a......|
00000010  90 c4 15 10 b5 e0 a6 48  de fd 23 96 14 29 b1 83  |.......H..#..)..|
]] for SKI [9ec09aa75cdf5b13256115a4d28cf3ba90c41510b5e0a648defd23961429b183], looking for Public key
2021-09-17 10:50:44.515 +08 [bccsp_p11] GetKey -> DEBU 01a Key not found using PKCS11: Public key not found [Key not found [00000000  9e c0 9a a7 5c df 5b 13  25 61 15 a4 d2 8c f3 ba  |....\.[.%a......|
00000010  90 c4 15 10 b5 e0 a6 48  de fd 23 96 14 29 b1 83  |.......H..#..)..|
]] for SKI [9ec09aa75cdf5b13256115a4d28cf3ba90c41510b5e0a648defd23961429b183]
2021-09-17 10:50:44.515 +08 [msp] getSigningIdentityFromConf -> DEBU 01b Could not find SKI [9ec09aa75cdf5b13256115a4d28cf3ba90c41510b5e0a648defd23961429b183], trying KeyMaterial field: Key not found. This is a dummy KeyStore
Failed getting key for SKI [[158 192 154 167 92 223 91 19 37 97 21 164 210 140 243 186 144 196 21 16 181 224 166 72 222 253 35 150 20 41 177 131]]
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/sw.(*CSP).GetKey
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/bccsp/sw/impl.go:170
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/pkcs11.(*impl).GetKey
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/bccsp/pkcs11/pkcs11.go:257
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp.(*bccspmsp).getSigningIdentityFromConf
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/msp/mspimpl.go:220
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp.(*bccspmsp).setupSigningIdentity
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/msp/mspimplsetup.go:401
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp.(*bccspmsp).preSetupV142
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/msp/mspimplsetup.go:586
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp.(*bccspmsp).setupV142
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/msp/mspimplsetup.go:647
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp.(*bccspmsp).Setup
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/msp/mspimpl.go:267
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cache.(*cachedMSP).Setup
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/msp/cache/cache.go:88
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp/mgmt.LoadLocalMspWithType
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/msp/mgmt/mgmt.go:33
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/common.InitCrypto
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/internal/peer/common/common.go:144
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/common.InitCmd
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/internal/peer/common/common.go:324
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/channel.glob..func1
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/internal/peer/channel/channel.go:102
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:746
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800
main.main
        /appl/src/fabric-2.2.3/cmd/peer/main.go:54
runtime.main
        /appl/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
        /appl/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
2021-09-17 10:50:44.515 +08 [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 01c Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /appl/blockchain/peerOrganizations/org1/users/Admin@org1/msp: KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo
```

Here is the token and object in SoftHSM:

```
[user@hyperledgerfabric ~]# pkcs11-tool --module /appl/softhsm/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so --token-label "fabric" --list-objects
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      tlspeer.org1
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=Default Company Ltd, CN=peer.org1
  ID:         746c73706565722e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      orderer.ordererOrg
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=ordererOrg, OU=orderer, CN=orderer.ordererOrg
  ID:         6f7264657265722e68616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   044104f8cab0e26330c5cde55afb3ffbffe0fee8a96cca7fcb08d7360e736b21552a337f0f29b1f68d708b296dcdc75922a9e709ffad6a3f3863f6ae039a71fac49d06
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      tlspeer.org1
  ID:         746c73706565722e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   044104ae4ae570e763654d9fa9f3bec3ffddde7402044153c32f3490e8f8d5a4c90be884385237fa9659914730ff38751bb3b9c8b046f7e9e6dc52b134ae247ff40ed0
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      tlsorderer.ordererOrg
  ID:         746c736f7264657265722e68616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   04410458679db1f667a4bcf3c0b13f62e80fe9a9d4982881b7772f192e9cabc20158e33299856d995a0fbbd7523fa69e9fe3e5543c8ea5e0dc327348ece7625cb96860
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      tlsca.org1
  ID:         746c7363612e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   0441047bfd15d2a4e46e74a77d4000c48235f2a9781842b3716b3c5cf26a0519766e75e49c0aac9c5939e0d54f8070acb2a82f232a5627abc4e9d2e00fc9adc1f6c66d
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      peer.org1
  ID:         706565722e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      tlsAdmin@org1
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=Default Company Ltd, CN=Admin@org1
  ID:         746c7341646d696e4066696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      ca.org1
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=org1, CN=ca.org1
  ID:         63612e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   044104de510ebd9f4de1dede7fb602ce17404222565b1214af54807d13b5fca21027e8f004efe5f924cfa5ada25db85757bbd887a5071ade0a0e13247ce5075ef36562
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      ca.org1
  ID:         63612e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      Admin@ordererOrg
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=ordererOrg, OU=admin, CN=Admin@ordererOrg
  ID:         41646d696e4068616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      tlsca.ordererOrg
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=ordererOrg, CN=tlsca.ordererOrg
  ID:         746c7363612e68616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      tlsca.org1
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=org1, CN=tlsca.org1
  ID:         746c7363612e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   0441040c778079386f8febd1b72bd4c04b387117ae83109cfbccb85c3a6d9f36fe195567c657bf14ea49fb6991bacd505469c07818e2ab34befee3a0d2f44f0ed4bfee
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      Admin@ordererOrg
  ID:         41646d696e4068616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      tlsorderer.ordererOrg
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=Default Company Ltd, CN=orderer.ordererOrg
  ID:         746c736f7264657265722e68616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      peer.org1
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=org1, OU=peer, CN=peer.org1
  ID:         706565722e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   044104372fd1ef78bd6ed5ee952c177fc1990cf20c6aebc72106f54bd9a6423192aa1ed5698447618b5ea2b0569508c8dce3587e94268e570734396bcda60650a6d17a
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      orderer.ordererOrg
  ID:         6f7264657265722e68616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   04410445fe15a00a608ccae5db578277fb2d31d14193161a317e2a9145be9a0dcfdadff534b2ee86fe0872ba1ef9a5868b7c23439544a7c0880485442053217e5a9239
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      tlsca.ordererOrg
  ID:         746c7363612e68616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   0441045ff498d46abb2dc1bb915a97d29b0713b3e448e2bc3253e83e972f7812c5d4a556a04dafb175630e45d97481e71476eef74a8439c5afe8b0a2d0c85bdc2ef282
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      Admin@org1
  ID:         41646d696e4066696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   04410487a8c34237457651cb0b87c6559d7d4fc6e055cf17fec1b2a42f6f22bbc0b4ea3d02b1336bc5d4cc8267dd01ce081a8ebd6d18ba8e41c2e241bda2bfdbdcb980
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      ca.ordererOrg
  ID:         63612e68616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      tlsAdmin@ordererOrg
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=Default Company Ltd, CN=Admin@ordererOrg
  ID:         746c7341646d696e4068616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   0441040c7c76519783ed1015354fa8e6130c340bcb89f10238da9f80d002bdc53851a30af2a2114697ba9832ec813506764399b370b1ccf664551b8730b083d198e933
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      tlsAdmin@org1
  ID:         746c7341646d696e4066696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Public Key Object; EC  EC_POINT 256 bits
  EC_POINT:   044104f0e26cf7dcee25b140769ed1ffd5e2b26608524656ea844d183e655c3be614da1b24b6503b36b3de72ceda78bb7535560eb40090016c810b92cf42a39ef9c587
  EC_PARAMS:  06082a8648ce3d030107
  label:      tlsAdmin@ordererOrg
  ID:         746c7341646d696e4068616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
  Usage:      encrypt, verify, wrap, derive
  Access:     local
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      Admin@org1
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=org1, OU=admin, CN=Admin@org1
  ID:         41646d696e4066696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
Certificate Object; type = X.509 cert
  label:      ca.ordererOrg
  subject:    DN: C=MY, ST=Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, L=Kuala Lumpur, O=ordererOrg, CN=ca.ordererOrg
  ID:         63612e68616c616c666f6f6470672e66696e6578757367726f75702e636f6d0a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the pre-built binaries of fabric do not have pkcs11 enabled. You need to build the peer and orderer binaries from source, specifying the tag `pkcs11` to create versions that support PKCS11

Comment: Any guide link for compiling the hyperledger fabric source ?

Comment: There is information in the hyperledger fabric docs, you could start here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/dev-setup/build.html

Comment: I have compiled with PKCS11 enabled for peer, but now the peer not able to find the KeyMaterial. I have updated with the details above. Is there any specific label that need to tally with fabric for it to find my token correctly ?

Comment: If you don't use fabric-ca-client to create your keys in the HSM then you need to attach an ID to the key attributes CKA_ID, CKA_LABEL (you could try to attach an ID that fabric by default expects but you will have to examine the fabric code base and create a tool that can generate that id for you to attach). That ID can be specified in AltID field as described in the AWS section here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/hsm.html (it seems the 2.2 docs are missing this)

Comment: I had checked, my certificate SKI (X509v3 Subject Key Identifier) matches the value in the debug log that it looking for, also I added the SKI as AltId in my yaml config file, but still it reported not able to find ...

Comment: It's not the X509v3 SKI that fabric uses, It does it's own calculation and calls it an SKI, I would suggest you use your own value and use the AltID field

Comment: I have also tried use the AltID field, but still no luck, same error message that it cannot find ... My AltId value is configured same as the CKA_ID in SoftHSM ...

Comment: So I have got AltID to work but I used fabric-ca-client to populate the keys and set the CKA_ID to AltID and the HSM I was using wasn't softhsm, so it worked in my scenario, not sure what else to suggest at this point. Not sure turning on debug would help either. Maybe softhsm has some logging you could turn on to see what ID is being sent and how it tries to compare ?

Comment: Yr ans and feedback gave me some direction to look into. I think is fabric v2.2.3 problem, i went thru again on the fabric github releases, and found that on v2.2.4 there is a bug fix on "pkcs11: Add SKI to CKA_ID mapping for BCCSP" (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/d2d031e4fd73f3a0d057b3d18ab4aefeb8601d13). Hence I upd to v2.2.4, but not sure why AltID still not working as expected, but I managed to get it work by using SHA256 of my public key and set into both X509v3 Subject Key Identifier, and the CKA_ID (without using AltID) and it works !

Comment: By referring to this article, https://superuser.com/questions/987588/can-i-get-a-fingerprint-of-an-ec-key-using-openssl ... here is how I correctly generate X509v3 Subject Key Identifier which is also fabric is using ... pkcs11-tool --module /appl/softhsm/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so --read-object --type pubkey --login --login-type user --pin 123456 --token-label "[your token label]" --label "[your label]" | dd ibs=26 skip=1 | openssl dgst -sha256 | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'